# extract a string from text in R according to the key

Tags: r, regex

I have a text "got the money from HDFC , the amount is $100 and delivered to apple." I have to extract HDFC, apple, $100 from the string using keywords(from,amount,delivered). and the result should be

```
credit  HDFC
money   $100
Debit   Apple.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take the [tour] and especially read [ask]. Questions are epxected to show some amount of effort already spent by the  author. Everything which looks like "here are my requirements, somebody give code" is not likely to get helpful answers. You could for example show some code which basically applies a regex and outputs the harvested string. Fine tuning it to get everything right is something which people at StackOverflow love to help with.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Yunnosch's comment, having my doubts about your question. Maybe this will get you started to rephrase. Use

```
from\s([^\s]+)\s,\sthe\samount\sis\s(\$[1-9][0-9]*)\sand\sdelivered\sto\s([^.]+)
```

and "credit" is \1, money is \2 and "Debit" is \3.

Comment: can you please explain it how to do it in R.